# How to simplify my Rails money converter module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Just out of curiosity:

Is there a way to simplify a file like this:

```
module Converter

  def hourly_rate
    hourly_rate_in_cents.to_d / 100 if hourly_rate_in_cents
  end

  def hourly_rate=(number)
    self.hourly_rate_in_cents = number.to_d * 100 if number.present?
  end

  def price
    price_in_cents.to_d / 100 if price_in_cents
  end

  def price=(number)
    self.price_in_cents = number.to_d * 100 if number.present?
  end  

  def amount
    amount_in_cents.to_d / 100 if amount_in_cents
  end

  def amount=(number)
    self.amount_in_cents = number.to_d * 100 if number.present?
  end

end
```

I am using these function because I need to store all the money related values as `integers` in my database, however I don't like the repitition in my code.

Comment: Could you share the database schema and the model.rb too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
module Converter

  def self.def_converter(name)
    define_method(name) do
      value_in_cents = send("#{name}_in_cents")
      value_in_cents.to_d / 100 if value_in_cents.present?
    end

    define_method("#{name}=") do |number|
      send("#{name}_in_cents=", number.to_d * 100) if number.present?
    end
  end

  def_converter(:hourly_rate)
  def_converter(:price)
  def_converter(:amount)

end
```